# Google App Engine settings substitution for Dev vs Online

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I am writing a Google App Engine (Java) application that reads data from a number of REST services, using OAuth for authentication. In order to support OAuth callbacks in my Development and Online environments, I have created 2 separate OAuth keys for the REST services - 1 that does a callback to 127.0.0.1 (development server) and 1 that does a callback to my real GAE website URL. This all works fine and happy.

Currently, to support this, I basically have a number of these statements throughout my code, anywhere that needs different values for Dev vs Online...

```
String devServer = request.getServerName();
if (devServer != null && devServer .equals("127.0.0.1")){
    oauthKey = "<my_dev_key>";
}
else {
    oauthKey = "<my_online_key>";
}
```

I was wondering whether GAE has any ability to auto-substitute different values for Development vs Online. I was thinking something like a 'settings' file that specifies 2 different values for a single setting, such that when the app is uploaded to GAE it replaces all setting references with the Online values. I would prefer that the values are substituted at upload-time rather than having a file sitting on the server with my Development settings in it, for security purposes.

Are there any alternatives that would be able to achieve a similar result without too much manual work every time I wish to upload a new version to GAE?

Comment: Not the solution you are looking for, but [ServerEnvironment](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Environment) may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the credential in different `Properties` files using something like Maven and its [Profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) feature to build an artifact for any specific environment.

Have a look to [this project](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/) for the Google App Engine Maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like it might be a step in the right direction